# How to use lighthouse npm using dynamic import() statement?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i am trying to import lighthouse using  dynamic import() statement as below but it is not working, and giving an error like :

`This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import("xxx/node_modules/lighthouse/core/index")' has no call signatures.`

```
let lighthouse = await import('lighthouse/core/index');
let runnerResult = await lighthouse(url, options);
```

i am trying to open lighthouse by dynamic import() in test cafe project.

Comment: I think it should be `let lighthouse = (await import('lighthouse/core/index')).default;`

Answer (score 0):

Use lighthouse directly,

```
const lighthouse = await import('lighthouse');
```

Or if you wish to use it by import then,

```
import lighthouse from "lighthouse";
```